# Implementing guice Provider with a parameterised type

Tags: java, generics, guice

So I am trying to implement the guice Provider interface,

```
public interface Provider<T> {
  T get();
}
```

and I have another interface called `Creator`

```
public interface Creator {
    void create();
}
```

and I want to create a Provider to bind different types of `Creator` when creating a number of `CreatePhases`.

```
private static final class CreatePhaseProvider<T> implements Provider<CreatePhase<T extends Creator>>
    {
        @Override
        public CreatePhase<T> get(){
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This gives me an error "Syntax error on token "extends" ,,". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static final class CreatePhaseProvider<T extends Creator> implements Provider<CreatePhase<T>>
    {
        @Override
        public CreatePhase<T> get(){
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Oops put the extends in the wrong place!